# Setting outlook's "Default sensitivity level" for mail also sets appointments private

Tags: microsoft-outlook

A collegue of mine configured her Outlook to set the "Default Sensitivity Level" to private. Outlook>File>Options>Mail>Default sensitivity level.

However, when she opens a meeting room calendar and books the room (simple drag to create a meeting, type her name, hit RETURN), the meeting appears as "private" in the meeting room too!

Since she is not the owner of the meeting room, she can't even see the meeting details, nor delete her own meeting.

This was not what she wanted, setting "default sensitivity level" under "mail" was supposed to only affect mails, not calendars.

Anyone got any ideas? We'd rather not go into addins or VBA if there are other possibilities...

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly when you book a room, you are actually sending your request via an email to the "room", that's why that setting affects that. Which version of Exchange are you using, and have the [IRM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351035(v=exchg.141).aspx) rules been configured beyond the defaults?

Comment: It's an Exchange 2010, and there's no additional IRM rules that I know of. I think you're right that booking a room sends an invisible e-mail, which now also is private, which turns the booking private - but it's not handy at all. Would there be a way to have default e-mails private but meeting e-mails not? (without VBA?)